# No parameterless constructor was found on 'TContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not really clear on why the error happens. When I first scaffold my project the migration and update-database commands ran fine but after few changes in the application I was getting [this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#error-no-parameterless-constructor-was-found). The only solution floating around is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext):

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext Create()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserCode> ApplicationUserCodes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

It works for me but the connection string is hard-coded inside the class which is not fine with me. Any clarifications as to why this error did not happen at one time and later it did is really appreciated and also a elegant solution than embedding connection string in class please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you have this

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(){          // << The reason....

    }
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
         : base(options)
    { }

   public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Another reason is that it was seeing the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder){}` override without the `base.OnModelCreating(builder);`  call inside the `OnModelCreating(){}` method at the top of the method itself.  Threw me for a loop as to why... then I tried a few things, low and behold it was a simple inclusion of the parameterless constructor it was looking was the culprit.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);   //<< Absolutely required at the top.
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

**EDIT**

//Startup.cs ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection")));
```

//appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MssqlLocalDb;Initial        Catalog=PilotSystemCore;Integrated Security=True",
"SqliteConnection" :  "Data Source=SqliteDbName.db"
 },
 "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
     "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Debug",
         "System": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Information"
   }
 }
}
```

NB: If you did any migrations with SqlServer before, the generated items are long valid redo the migrations.

Comment: I have updated my post with how my DbContext looks like.

Comment: You can find my StartUp and DbContext code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7641#issuecomment-290339592).